# Where CCLayer has gone in API ref?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Trying to find reference for `CCLayer` in Cocos2D 2.0. It appears that `CCLayer` is no more in class hierarchy since version 1.0. Any reason why it was removed? I see it does exist in API itself, but the reference is just gone, so would like to know the reason behind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple other classes missing too. Reason: incorrect use of doxygen comments. I'm [hosting the correct cocos2d api references here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/) which include those missing classes. I also split them by platform otherwise you would be missing the platform specific casses as well.